# Power off Antminer D3 (without ssh access)

Tags: antminer

I want to power off an Antminer D3.

I have read online that the best way to do it is by connecting via ssh and executing `poweroff`.

However, I cannot login from my Mac to the miner with `ssh -p 22 root@192.168.0.xxx` or `ssh root@192.168.0.xxx`.

It does not accept the default password "root":

> Permission denied, please try again.

How can I log in and do I really have to shut down the miner this way? It makes sense to not turn off the fans immediately by unplugging the PSU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default password `admin` for user `root` worked.

Comment: They don’t really stop mining if you shut it down.

Comment: @eponymous why don’t they stop mining? What is shutting down then?

Comment: You can turn off the control CPU but the mining chips are always connected to the power. I was imagining you were trying to schedule it’s usage.

Comment: @eponymous I intended to gracefully shut the miner down where the fans would still run some time after it stopped mining, so the chips don’t overheat.

Comment: They’re designed for extremely high heat operation, there’s no danger in just unplugging it. It will probably happier with continuous operating rather than heating and cooling cycles.